# C# Selenium web driver can't tick a check box

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, checkbox

Have an issue here. My scenario need to tick a check box to be completed and the selenium web driver can't do that as the check box as an element has two location Identifiers in selenium IDE (Xpath and Id).

[image]

When defining the element by one only the code stops at the click action and can't tick the check box, the code is

```
public void Select_requirement_type_Checkbox_click()
    {
        var Checkbox = _webDriver.FindElementByXPath("//nav/ul/li[3]/tree-renderer/div/rm-checkbox/div/label");
        _webDriver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", Checkbox);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used selenium much, but I always tried to make it act as a user clicking their way through a form/page...

So instead of trying to call one of the click event handlers attached to the checkbox, I just called the click() method of the element - and let the browser handle the event.

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(sel)).Click();
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian for help.
And sorry for being late to check.